# How to extract value from foreach loop by json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have php result set, and from these result i am extracting value using php foreach loop. I put the foreach loop value in array `$summery[]`. but when i try to print value its print value at once. but i need separate value/result set for each foreach loop as json code so that i can print each result separately. My foreach loop following :

```
foreach($result_UserWrSet as $UserWrInfo) {
        $summery[]=$UserWrInfo['wr_id'];
        $summery[]=$UserWrInfo['wr_number'];
        $summery[]=$UserWrInfo['wr_title'];
        $dateFlag=1;
        $result_StartDate = $WrDates ->getDateById($UserWrInfo['date_id'],$dateFlag);
        $result_EndDate = $WrDates ->getDateById($UserWrInfo['date_id'],$dateFlag);
        $summery[]=$result_StartDate;
        $sql_GetUserName = "SELECT user_name FROM user_information where user_id='$UserWrInfo[user_id]'";
        $result_GetUserName = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_GetUserName);
        $num_GetUserName = mysqli_num_rows($result_GetUserName);
        if ($num_GetUserName > 0){
            $UserNameByIdRos = $result_GetUserName->fetch_assoc();
            $UserNameById=$UserNameByIdRos['user_name'];
        }
        else {$UserNameById=NULL;}
        $summery[]=$UserNameById;
        $result_CurrentHop = $WrDates ->getCurrentHopByWrId($UserWrInfo['wr_id']);
        $result_CurrentHopName = $WrDates ->GetHopsNameById($result_CurrentHop);
        $summery[]=$result_CurrentHopName;
        $result_EndDate = $WrDates ->completedDate($UserWrInfo['wr_id']);
        $summery[]=$result_EndDate;
    }
print json_encode($summery);
```

My result become

```
["69","010116-69","Wr test","01\/01\/16 18:45 PM","planner","Done","01\/01\/16 19:16 PM","68","010116-","This is title","01\/01\/16 18:44 PM","planner","Done"]
```

but i need :

```
[["69","010116-69","Wr test","01\/01\/16 18:45 PM","planner","Done"],["01\/01\/16 19:16 PM","68","010116-","This is title","01\/01\/16 18:44 PM","planner","Done"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code, you need to use another array in which all the sub array's to be pushed and encode that array after pushing all the items into it

```
<?php 
$dataArray = array(); /// empty array in which sub array's to be pushed..
foreach($result_UserWrSet as $UserWrInfo) {
        $summery= array();
        $summery[]=$UserWrInfo['wr_id'];
        $summery[]=$UserWrInfo['wr_number'];
        $summery[]=$UserWrInfo['wr_title'];
        $dateFlag=1;
        $result_StartDate = $WrDates ->getDateById($UserWrInfo['date_id'],$dateFlag);
        $result_EndDate = $WrDates ->getDateById($UserWrInfo['date_id'],$dateFlag);
        $summery[]=$result_StartDate;
        $sql_GetUserName = "SELECT user_name FROM user_information where user_id='$UserWrInfo[user_id]'";
        $result_GetUserName = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_GetUserName);
        $num_GetUserName = mysqli_num_rows($result_GetUserName);
        if ($num_GetUserName > 0){
            $UserNameByIdRos = $result_GetUserName->fetch_assoc();
            $UserNameById=$UserNameByIdRos['user_name'];
        }
        else {$UserNameById=NULL;}
        $summery[]=$UserNameById;
        $result_CurrentHop = $WrDates ->getCurrentHopByWrId($UserWrInfo['wr_id']);
        $result_CurrentHopName = $WrDates ->GetHopsNameById($result_CurrentHop);
        $summery[]=$result_CurrentHopName;
        $result_EndDate = $WrDates ->completedDate($UserWrInfo['wr_id']);
        $summery[]=$result_EndDate;
        ////Push sub array i.e summary into the main array...
        $dataArray[] = $summery;
}
print json_encode($dataArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a multidimensional array, you can follow below code:

```
$result_UserWrSet = array(
 '0' => array('wr_id'=>'12','wr_number' =>'785', 'wr_title' => 'title1'),
 '1' => array('wr_id'=>'12','wr_number' =>'785', 'wr_title' => 'title1'));

foreach($result_UserWrSet as $key => $UserWrInfo) {
    $summery[$key][]=$UserWrInfo['wr_id'];
    $summery[$key][]=$UserWrInfo['wr_number'];
    $summery[$key][]=$UserWrInfo['wr_title'];
}

print json_encode($summery);
output: [["12","785","title1"],["12","785","title1"]]
```

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are just adding new items to a one dimensional array. You need to create a separate array per result, like this:

```
foreach($result_UserWrSet as $UserWrInfo) {
    $item = array();

    // Change all $summary in the loop to: $item, like this:
    $item[]=$UserWrInfo['wr_id'];
    $item[]=$UserWrInfo['wr_number'];
    $item[]=$UserWrInfo['wr_title'];

    //...and so on

    // Then add this last in your loop:
    $summary[] = $item;
}
```

This will create one array per iteration that is put in the main array, which then becomes a multi dimensional array.